# android share clickable string url with indication google maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-intent

I have a listview of elements. Each element is a different place and when I click into one of this I open a google map intent with the way to go.

Sometimes I need to share the address (for example "Colosseo, Piazza del Colosseo 1, 00184 Roma RM".

How do I share this string with a clickable url? I want to share it and permit other people to click inside it and open google map

This is how I create the intent:

```
public void OpenMaps(Context context) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Ti porto a: "Colosseo, Piazza del Colosseo 1, 00184 Roma RM", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Uri address = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=Colosseo,+Piazza+del+Colosseo+1,+00184+Roma+RM");
    Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, address);
    context.startActivity(mapIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you'll like this:

```
private String UrlMap(String s) {
    try {
        String url = "https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=" + URLEncoder.encode(s, "UTF-8");
        return url;
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

return "";
}
```

I don't know how to set a custom caption, to avoid seeing the entire url